# Conditional Output Based On Current Tailwind CSS Screen Size

Tags: php, laravel, conditional-statements, tailwind-css, laravel-blade

I'm aware how to apply different styling based on the screen size using Tailwind CSS, however, rather than applying "hidden" to a div at a certain screen size which hides all content within that div, I would like for only the div to be removed and the content within that div to remain on the page.

This is my code:

```
<div class="mx-auto mt-16 max-w-2xl lg:max-w-none">
            <div class="mx-auto bg-white mt-6 lg:h-[40rem] overflow-hidden">
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-6 gap-12">
                    <div class="lg:col-span-2">
                        <div class="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-1 lg:col-span-1 mb-4">
                            <!-- Image 0 -->
                            <div class="flex justify-center">
                                <x-curator-glider
                                    class="h-full"
                                    media="{{ $keyHighlightSection2Images[0]['image'] }}"
                                    format="webp"
                                    loading="lazy"
                                    quality="80"
                                    width="800"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-1 lg:col-span-1">
                            <!-- Image 3 -->
                            <div class="flex justify-center">
                                <x-curator-glider
                                    class="h-full"
                                    media="{{ $keyHighlightSection2Images[3]['image'] }}"
                                    format="webp"
                                    loading="lazy"
                                    quality="80"
                                    width="800"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-1 lg:col-span-2">
                        <!-- Image 1 (middle) -->
                        <div class="flex justify-center lg:mt-48">
                            <x-curator-glider
                                class="h-full"
                                media="{{ $keyHighlightSection2Images[1]['image'] }}"
                                format="webp"
                                loading="lazy"
                                quality="80"
                                width="800"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lg:col-span-2">
                        <div class="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-1 lg:col-span-1">
                            <!-- Image 2 -->
                            <div class="flex justify-center mb-4">
                                <x-curator-glider
                                    class="h-full"
                                    media="{{ $keyHighlightSection2Images[2]['image'] }}"
                                    format="webp"
                                    loading="lazy"
                                    quality="80"
                                    width="800"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-1 lg:col-span-1">
                            <!-- Image 4 -->
                            <div class="flex justify-center mb-16 lg:mb-0">
                                <x-curator-glider
                                    class="h-full"
                                    media="{{ $keyHighlightSection2Images[4]['image'] }}"
                                    format="webp"
                                    loading="lazy"
                                    quality="80"
                                    width="800"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This should look like this:

[image]

Then, if i removed the divs with class "lg:col-span-2", it gives me this view in smaller screens (which i want):

[image]

This is within my blade file. How can I display the following div when on large screens but have it removed on anything below "lg":

```
<div class="lg:col-span-2">
```

If I don't include the "lg:col-span-2" divs, this is how it looks on larger screens:

[image]

Comment: you cannot split the inner content of element from its parent by css, you could do that in javascript but that is bad thinking, you should give the div properties so the defaults do not affect its visual, so it basically looks like the div is not even there. i dont know tailwind-css but generally for example its like `@media (max-width: lg-size){ display: inline; }`

Comment: My issue is that I need to have both divs with class "col-span-1 sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-1 lg:col-span-1" separate from each other in md or smaller screens, but to visually have what i need in the larger screen, I need to have the two divs contained within a parent div.

Comment: then i guess the "span" in class name indicate if they are drawn as inline or block, if that is what you mean by being separated.

Comment: I've updated the question with all my code and the layout I want to achieve. On even smaller screens, It will just be 1 image per row.

Comment: why do you even have the `<div class="lg:col-span-2">` there ? from the layout it seems that parent is responsible for col count by the `grid-cols-*` class, so imo placing col into col brake the structure, col have meaning only while being inside grid-cols parent, that may not exclude having both on single element tho

Comment: I've updated the question to show you why I need that div to be included @Kazz

Comment: yea and do you know why it looks like that on large screens ? because of "lg:grid-cols-6" class on parent div, you could change it to lets say "lg:grid-cols-3". i think if you had more images displayed it would be broken at your initial code state (with div)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like for only the div to be removed and the content within that div to remain on the page.

That can be done using `display: contents`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box:

> `contents` - These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.

Not sure if tailwind already comes with classes to apply this at certain breakpoints; if not, you will have to add it yourself.